# How do I specify which item to have selected/active in this jQuery accordion widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am building a site off of [this framework](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/16/fluid/jquery/), and am trying to customize how the section menu accordion functions. I want the selected/active item to be reflect what page is currently displayed. Currently, as you can see by the code, it selects the first item by default:

```
SectionMenu : function(){
$("#section-menu")
    .accordion({
        "header": "a.menuitem"
    })
    .bind("accordionchangestart", function(e, data) {
        data.newHeader.next().andSelf().addClass("current");
        data.oldHeader.next().andSelf().removeClass("current");
    })
    .find("a.menuitem:first").addClass("current")
    .next().addClass("current");
},
```

So far I have been able to specify the item to be selected with this on the page:

```
<script>
    $("#section-menu")
    .accordion({
        "header": "a.menuitem",
        "collapsible": true,
        "active":4
    });
</script>
```

The issue at hand now is that the first item still remains highlighted as current. I have attached an image to better illustrate what I am describing:

[image: menu]

Where should I go from here to square this away?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I commented the last two lines of the `SectionMenu` block, and that solved the issue of the first item always being selected as current. Now I just need to be able to do `.addClass("current")` to the appropriate item and this should work.

## Solution

As in my last edit, I removed the last two lines in the `SectionMenu` block, and added the following code to the `<script>` portion of each page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#section-menu")
    .find("[href^='<HREF>']:first").addClass("current")
    .next().addClass("current");
</script>
```

Where `<HREF>` is the page name. This properly selects and applies the CSS to the appropriate node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `navigation` option `true` for href-based state-saving. [Documentation here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-navigation).

```
$("#section-menu")
.accordion({
    "header": "a.menuitem",
    "collapsible": true,
    "navigation": true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately, adding this to the code makes every item in the menu expanded.

Comment: Ok, I changed something up that got me back to where I was when I posted this question. I added `href="page.html"` to the parent `<li>`, and this selected and expanded the proper node. However, the first item still has the "current" CSS applied to it.

Comment: Do I need to somehow use `.find()` in order to apply the style properly? Check my latest edit to see what I have updated to be one step closer.

Comment: I think accordion script adds a class to current element. You may find that class and replace it's contents with the content of the "current" class.

Comment: Yes it does. In this version of it, the last two lines of the `SectionMenu` block always selects the first one (`.find("a.menuitem:first").addClass("current").next().addClass("current")`). I need to somehow modify that part to apply the CSS to the active item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#section-menu")
    .accordion({
        "header": "a.menuitem",
        "collapsible": true,
        "active": <INDEX>
    });
</script>
```

Where `<INDEX>` is the `<INDEX>th` `a.menuitem` element of your accordion

You can read more on [accordion's documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-active)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where do I place this? I put it in my `<script>` tag, but that took me one step backwards. Now the first item is once again expanded and selected as current.